# Comma and Rephrasing of " and when needed"

Tags: phrases, commas

I am writing a Cover letter and my paragraph reads as follows:
(the last line sounds somewhat clumsy to me).

> I demonstrate ample professional experience in the academic writing sector and communication sector acquired at prestigious international universities, research centers and organizations. Having acted as a lecturer and consultant at international universities and media schools has complemented my skills with confident public speaking. My background as an international editor and writer has equipped me with the skill to craft clear, concise **and when needed** compelling content.

Is there a better way to express it, please? Grazie mille.

Comment: Are there circumstances where you wouldn't want your content to be compelling? I'd miss out the 'and when needed', leaving your crafted content more concise and compelling.

Comment: My suggestions are: avoid repeating 'sector' and use sectors one time, replace 'background' with 'experiences'. Thus, "I demonstrate ample professional experience in the academic writing and communication sectors acquired....", or "....in the sectors of academic writing and communication acquired...."       " My experiences as an international editor and writer have equipped...."

Comment: @mahmudkoya That section is not the area the OP is questioning. You somehow managed to not reference the bolded sentence at all.

Answer (score 1):

> My background as an international editor and writer has equipped me with the skill to craft clear, concise and when needed compelling content.

I would place commas

> My background as an international editor and writer has equipped me with the skill to craft clear, concise and, when needed, compelling content.

so.
With the commas, there is nothing clumsy that I note. Without the commas, the reading is not so smooth. I assume "straight to the point" writing is what would normally be expected. Otherwise, "when needed"  is not needed.

Comment: @all. Thank you for the insights & comments. I truly appreciate it! 1.) I agree that the commas dividing the adjectives would allow a better flow.

Comment: 2.) My aim of this paragraph, specifically of the last sentence is to be punchy and clear, i.e. " straight to the point" as you suggest with perspicacity. The " needed" did indeed sound " not needed" to me.

Comment: STILL- I wanted to tell the editors - that "in case they need a fun, engaging and creative content" I am fully competent to provide that as well. " for clear & concise - Imagine: clear instructive content entry in an encyclopaedia ,literature summary for library catalogue ( was one work offer) and then it could cover also creative writing jobs.  As i feel if I say only the first two " c" ' s there is no room for the 'compelling, captivating, enticing content." ...

Comment: @Spagirl  
Good point: "Are there circumstances where you wouldn't want your content to be compelling?"  I have noted it in the above comment: I imagine the encyclopedia entry is supposed to be " not too compelling". - Yes- I see now- the option to leave that out would indeed sound better. Great eyes for spotting that! Thank you.

Comment: Di niente.....prego,

Comment: @John

Lovely! Do you speak Italian?:) I do not speak Italian ( yet) yet I am now ( once in a while), in a full immersion of the Italian opera- and I simply love saying “Millions of graceful” thank you-s. Have a great week! ( I have "just" realized I have not posted this message- it has been in my draft- folder...prepac!

Comment: @Jana .. I hope you enjoy the opera. Non parlo Italiano..except when I have to, and then Spanish with Italian words.